# Additional "internal" access point with own DHCP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp, tomato

I am building myself a home automation system which will have some networked devices that connect to wifi and a few that connect via a cable. But I want those devices to be somewhat separate from my main home network. As in - they will have their own wifi access point and they need to be able to operate correctly even if my main router goes down (either because I am playing with the settings, or something went wrong).

What I also want is for the devices to be able to talk to one anther as if they are in the same local network. I want to be able to access my home automation devices from my primary network and I want my home automation devices to access devices in my primary network.

I basically want an additional access point, but it also needs a DHCP server since it needs to work without the primary router being online.

Both of these routers are running the latest Tomato Shibby firmware. My primary router currently has classic local address of 192.168.1.1 with the subnet mask 255.255.255.0 and the DHCP server is configured to hand out addresses from 192.168.1.100-200. And I was thinking of having my home automation devices on addresses 192.168.2.x.

Is that possible, and how can I do that?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But if you intend to directly access devices on the 192.168.2.x network from your primary network you need to do some network trickery by disabling NAT on the secondary router and setting up static routes on your primary network devices. Or you need to do one-to-one NAT on the secondary router effectively giving all devices on the secondary network an IP address on the primary network. It’s possible to do the first option, with just a static route on your primary router, however this will cause “asymmetrical” routing and some devices might reject that for security reasons

Comment: @Appleoddity I can't say any of those sound too appealing. What about enabling DHCP server on my home automation router, but giving out addresses in the 192.168.1.201-250 range? Or would that cause issues?

Comment: That won’t work. You’d be better off doing a twist on Bob’s answer. Use your primary router for the routing and DHCP with a third virtual interface/network and simply use your secondary router as a simple wireless access point plugged in to the third interface. That way, there is no complicated setup and everything connected to the wireless access point can continue to function even if the primary router is down - assuming it’s not down longer than the DHCP lease.

Answer (score 0):

Just one route can do that.

basic -> network: add a LAN `br3` with dhcp on, range 192.168.2.x

advanced -> VLAN: add a VLAN `vlan3`. Assign different ports to the primary VLAN and new VLAN(`vlan3`). This is where cable is plugged. Bridge `vlan3` to `br3`

advanced -> virtual wireless: add a new SSID bridged to `br3`

It's easy. I think that's done (not tested yet). You can try, if it doesn't work, maybe we need to edit "LAN access"

update:

You want seperated two networks and two routers, you just need to deal with routing table.

```
router1 -- PCs
         -- router2 --- automating devices
```

Router2's WAN is connected to router1's LAN port (router1 as router2's gateway). Set router2's WAN IP static.

Router2 serves DHCP range 192.168.2.x to it's LAN.

Edit router1's routing table, add item: destination `192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.x(router2's WAN IP)`

If you power down router1, router2 still works.

Comment: That's not really what I want though. I know I can have a virtual wireless network with it's own subnet (that is what I am already using for my guest network - except not bridged to my primary network). What I want is a physically separate box with it's own DHCP server. That way I can replace my primary router, reboot it if the internet isn't working, ... without affecting my home automation network.

Comment: I followed your updated answer and I can't access my 192.168.2.x devices from my primary network. I can access my 192.168.1.x devices from the second router though. I can also access the internet from the second router. I added the following static routing table entry to my primary router: IP - 192.168.1.0, Gateway: 192.168.1.2 (second routers IP), Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0, Metric: 0, Interface: LAN.

Comment: It should be 192.168.2.0, instead of 192.168.1.0 , in routing table

Comment: My mistake... I was 2.0 not 1.0. I just typed it in incorrectly here.
But in the end I actually decided to go with the virtual wireless as you mentioned in the first post and I will just set up the other router as an offline backup. It is less of a hassle to manage.